# Как AirBNB запоминает пользователя?

Tags: javascript

При удалении кукисов, чистке кеша, а также смене IP сайт по-прежнему выводит последние запросы. Как он хранит информацию на клиенте? Кажется, я упускаю какую-то простую вещь..

Comment: На странице AirBnB есть трекинговые пиксели других поставщиков данных: google и facebook

Comment: Вообще, помимо кук [есть масса других способов](https://habrahabr.ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/321294/) идентифицировать пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Точно! Среди сторонних скриптов был бинг еще парочку. Вычистил куки от них и заблокировал эти скрипты носкриптом - сервис опознать не смог.